I have over 400 '3XX redirect in sitemap' errors in Ahrefs and no idea how to solve it
(Please bear with me as I provide an unnecessary amount of context.)
I have been running a website on Wordpress for around 6 months, and it has been slowly growing in traffic, until about 3 weeks ago when my Google search impressions and traffic suddenly plummeted. I am very new to SEO and I'm managing this website on my own, so it took a couple of weeks before I decided this wasn't just bad luck, there must be something wrong that is causing Google to nuke my SEO performance.
I eventually discovered the 'Core web vitals' tab in GSC, which said 40 URLs were 'poor'. I quickly found someone on Fiverr to fix this for me and as of today, it looks like Google have finally re-indexed the problem URLs since the Fiverr guy implemented his fix.
However, now that I have accepted the harsh reality that Google WILL penalise me if I don't fix my website's issues, which are never obvious to me as a complete novice, I realise now is probably a good time for me to stop ignoring the weekly emails I get from Ahrefs about issues on my site - see below for latest report.

In particular, I can see I have 489 '3XX redirect in sitemap' issues:

When I click on this to get a better look at what might be the problem, I see it's pretty much all image URLs.

I have no idea why images would have 3XX redirect issues, this means very little to me indeed - I just want to know what I need to do how to fix this, and how I can prevent it from happening in the future. I know terms like "sitemap" and I understand that the sitemap needs to be updated so that Google knows how and where to look at your site when indexing its pages - but that's as far as my knowledge goes. I wouldn't know how or where to fix sitemap issues. (If it helps, I know I have the AIOSEO plugin which is connected to my Google Search Console - frankly I had assumed it would automatically handle these issues).
I would massively appreciate any kind of explanation and guidance!

If you go to any image in your admin's media area, you will see that it has both a URL and an "attachment page".  The attachment page is something of a deprecated feature, as it's been off by default since WordPress 6.4.  It used to allow you to display images in a page of their own, which in reality has very little use.
Presumably for backwards compatibility reasons, every image still gets an attachment page URL, which unless your theme says to do otherwise, will just redirect to the image URL.  This is what you are seeing - the sitemap contains the attachment page URLs and they redirect to the image URL.
I don't believe this is core WordPress behaviour, so I'd look in the AIOSEO settings, or whatever extensions you are using to generate a sitemap.  You may be able to remove these.
Whilst image sitemaps do exist, most sites will not need a sitemap for their images.  To be honest, most sites don't need a sitemap at all unless they're huge or have crawling issues.

Thank you, this is very helpful. I will look at the AIOSEO plugin and see if I can remove images from the sitemap. Thanks for explaining the context of the issue as well, much appreciated.

You do not have to remove images from sitemap. Just perform this in AIOSEO:

Source:
Excluding Images from the XML Sitemap

The topic is too broad as there are many issues and many fixes for each one.
You need to start from the worse offenders, which are 4xx and broken links errors.  Planned 4xx and 3xx errors may be fine.  Unplanned ones need fixing.
When you don't understand a particular issues, post it as a separate question.

Totally agree, with so many bugs, it's better to start tackling things gradually.

Okay, all I’m asking for help with is how to address the 3XX redirect issues, which is why that’s what I’ve highlighted that in the screenshots, and why that’s the subject of the title. I am indeed planning to address the other issues separately, but I’m starting with the most significant issue I’m aware of (489 3XX redirections).
